# Cannot record macro in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

When I click "Record macro" a message box appears with:

> "Unable to record a macro".

- I saved the file in .xlsm extension
- I checked macro settings (e.g. Trust Center)
- VBA is installed
- I tried to reinstall Excel and repair

Comment: @FaneDuru as I said in post, that did not work

Comment: @FaneDuru i reinstalled it as well. I mentioned it in post too...

Comment: Sorry, I did not read till the end... Do you have Personal.xlsb open? What do you select when try recording a macro? I mean in 'Store macro in' text box.

Comment: I am trying to store macro in "This workbook".

Comment: Does this "ThisWorkbook" have at least a macro in it? Is it a xlsm type? If not, try having a xlsm workbook open and try writing a simple sub: `Sub Test1` `MsgBox "Test..."` `End Sub`. And try recording the macro in it.

Comment: Yes this is xlms type, i said it in the post. I had created one macro in VBA i successfully runned it but it only works in VBA editor, macro does not appear in excel.

Comment: Btw. "This workbook" is not name of excel file. It's one of three storing options to store macros.

Comment: I know what "This Workbook" means. I missed a space. Please, try creating a Personal.xlsb file on path: "C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART". Then open it, or restart Excel. It will be automatically open. Then, try recording the macro in it.

Comment: I had tried it before and i tried it now but it did not work.

Comment: Can you record a macro in Word 2010?

Comment: Does the file you're trying to record a macro in trigger a macro on opening? If so, is that running and causing you not being able to record any?

Comment: *A shot in the dark*: Can you check something for me? Go to Windows Settings (**Shortcut Key: Win Button + I**) - Language. Check what is the language set there? If it is not English, can you set it to English and then try recording again?